# Vim - easily edit filter result

Tags: vim, filtering

I would like to use something like [vils](http://www.freebsdsoftware.org/sysutils/vils.html) for vim buffers.

Example:

```
a
b
a
b
```

Search for "a" (`:g/a/`)

Output:

```
a
a
```

and then edit the output as if it were a normal buffer.
When I'm done it should map my changes line by line back to the original buffer.

How do I do that?

PS: I could probably use `:%s/../../` or something like that, but it wouldn't be nearly as comfortable as it could be. (Even if the completion in the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> buffer would work.)

Comment: I'd like to use this for hiding the comments in configuration files.

Comment: your best option is keep hiding the lines on which there is no search string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Qfreplace http://github.com/thinca/vim-qfreplace

1. add some into quickfix. ex: grep foo **/*
2. type :Qfreplace on quickfix
3. change lines as you want.
4. :w

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The feature you're talking about sounds like `occure`/`narrow-to-region` in emacs.

In vim, you can type this command:

```
:vimgrep pattern %
```

Then type `:cw` to open the quickfix-list.

You can use mouse click or `:cn`/`:cp` to navigate to make changes.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't work for me... The list opens, but when I try to modify it I get `E21: Cannot make changes, 'Modifiable' is off`, and then if I do `:set modifiable` to override that, the changes aren't reflected in the original file.

Comment: it's now 10 years ago... if you are in the quickfix-list and hit enter on the desired line, the cursor jumps in the original File to this desired line. Then you can make changes in the original File. 
It is not designed to make changes in the quickfix-list. That is why you get the E21 Error

Answer (score 1):

As long as the matching lines span a single range of consecutive lines, the [NrrwRgn plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075) may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I usually copy the lines to the end of the document

```
:g/a/t$
```

If you want, you can set a mark at the 'former' end-of-document:

```
:$mark a
```

So, now you can actually edit the `'a,$` part of your document as you would normally, including saving it to somewhere else:

```
:'a,$d | new | put!
```

---

The following works as well: you can yank, appending to a register `a`:

```
:g/a/yank A
```

Of course, you *may* want to clear register a before starting:

```
:let @a=""
```

Comment: nice pragmatic one :)

Answer (score -1):

`g/../` can be combined with commands like

```
:g/^a/ s/a/a.txt/
```

to change for example every 'a' to 'a.txt'. See ':h :g'

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants. I think he wants to hide some lines, edit the other lines and when saving save the whole files, i.e. with the lines that where hidden.